# How to indicate to TS that value in store has value even though it's optional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following case:

I have a standard store with optional items in it.

I also have a tree of elements which rely on that store. I also select `{account}` in multiple components.

For business logic, I had to check at the very top if account is set. If it is not, I don't render the components which rely on it.

How can I tell TS that even though the value is optional in store I'm 100% sure it is NOT undefined?

Example code:

```
// store
interface Account {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface AppState {
  account?: Account;
}

const initialState: AppState = {};

const accountSlice = createSlice({
  name: "account",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAccount(state: AppState, action: PayloadAction<Account | undefined>) {
      state.account = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

// component
const GrandChild = () => {
  const { account } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state, shallowEqual);
  return <>{account.name}</>;
};

const Child = () => {
  const { account } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state, shallowEqual);
  return account ? <GrandChild /> : <>account not set</>;
};

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch(setAccount({ id: 0, name: "john" }));
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/required-reducer-ysts49?file=/src/App.tsx

I know I can do this:

`const { account } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state, shallowEqual) as Account;`

but this seems very hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: When you use it, you can do `account!.name`. The exclamation mark is for asserting that it isn't undefined or null.

Comment: Also but not related to TS you can do ``account?.name``

Comment: yes, I can. But `!` defeats the purpose of TS (like `as`), and `?` is the current solution. I'm guessing there is no way to pass a generic or smth. And even then the issue will remain the same. We will force a type. I'll leave this open in case I missed smth big

Answer (score 3):

Well you know that `Grandchild` wont be rendered if `account` is undefined. so why not pass account as a property to the Grandchild component. This way you could define the property as never being undefined. And since you only render Grandchild after you checked that `account` isn't undefined you should be able to pass `account` as the property to the component (and since you defined the property as not being undefined TS will not object to `account.name` in your Grandchild component.

I don't know redux however - I have never used it and don't know anything about it, so I don't know if this answer is compatible with that or if redux will cause some issues I couldn't forsee.

I've written a little bit of code of how this could look (but as I already said, I don't know how to use redux, so you'll probably have to take my idea and write it so everything works) - so my code example is probably more of a visualization of what I mean than a solution.

```
const GrandChild = (account: Account) => {
  return <>{account.name}</>;
};

const Child = () => {
  const { account } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state, shallowEqual);
  return account ? <GrandChild account={account} /> : <>account not set</>;
};
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go. If the `<GrandChild>` is deeply nested again, using an extra context/a nested store might be useful for the account

Comment: This is exactly the case. The whole point of redux is to avoid prop drilling ;) I was thinking about wrappers that test but it makes no sense. I think `!` and `as` are the best bets here if we really **know** the value is there